# Excel 2016 VBA - Copy is extremely slow

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I recently upgraded excel from 2010 to 2016(32bits) and suddenly the code that took 5sec to complete now takes forever. Even simple copy operation like the code below takes about half a minute to run.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
Next i
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

EDIT: Below is the "real" code that @Comintern requested, there are about 1000 copies but it takes forever to run:

```
For i = 3 To lRow1        
     Select Case Range(cType & i).Value
        Case "Order"
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy wsOrder.Rows(lRowOrder + 1)
            lRowOrder = lRowOrder + 1
        Case "UP"
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy wsUP.Rows(lRowUP + 1)
            lRowUP = lRowUP + 1
        Case "Cancel"
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy wsCancel.Rows(lRowCancel + 1)
            lRowCancel = lRowCancel + 1
        Case "Edit"
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy wsEdit.Rows(lRowEdit + 1)
            lRowEdit = lRowEdit + 1
        Case ""
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy wsOther.Rows(lRowOther + 1)
            lRowOther = lRowOther + 1
    End Select

Next
```

Comment: I once had an issue with Excel being slow and it was due to a default printer not being set up.

Comment: @Comintern I use copy because I want to copy not only the value but also cell format. This code here is just an example for ease of understanding. In my real code, I use loop to divide data into different sheets.

Comment: @HilaDG Thanks for the suggestion, I also read this on another website but it didn't help me in this case.

Comment: Shouldnt you only be specifying the range on the right side of that function call? As in only `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)`

Comment: Also, is this the only code in this subroutine? It doesn't seem like copying maybe 10 values should really slow things down much

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I'm sorry, It was just like you said, the value should not be there, I edited the post. The problem is only copying 10 range to another sheet would take half a minute.

Comment: Just for a frame of reference on the performance, how many rows are there (a typical value for `lRow1`)?

Comment: @Comintern lRow1 should be about 300-600. And the operation took a bout 5 sec when I was using office 2010. Now it takes forever...

Comment: How much of the rest of the code is reasonable to post? What you’ve dropped in seems totally fine but I’m suspicious of the surrounding code. How have you narrowed the slow part down to this?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 yeah, I'm 100% percent sure it's the copy, the first section of code I posted is the code of the whole test sub that I created. And it took half a minute to copy 10 times ...

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem.  Excel would take several minutes to copy a part of the worksheet, say an area of 12x500 cells.  In my case, it turned out that **the cells had picked up some invisible graphics**, probably from their origin on a webpage.  So, one thing to check for, if you experience excel hanging up on copy operations, is the presence of image objects in your work.

There's a quick procedure here to find and remove them:
https://excel.tips.net/T003018_Deleting_All_Graphics.html